# Access username from basic authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I have a MVC project with uses Identity. This enables users to sign up to the site and create a profile.

I have a separate WebAPI class to allow Embedded GSM devices to communicate with the server. Users are able to sign up and add many GSM units to their profile.  I've had to use a Basic Authentication filter for the embedded GSM devices as it they are unable to cache a token / cookie.

My question is, how do i look up the username of the request within a webAPI controller?  i've tried accessing the user with RequestContext.Principal as per suggestions, but it returns null.

Controller:

```
 [BasicAuthentication]
 public void Post([FromBody]string value)
 {
    // Get username from request for database lookup?
 }
```

Filter:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
        else
        {
            string authenticationToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
            string decodedAuthenticationToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationToken));
            string[] usernamePasswordArray = decodedAuthenticationToken.Split(':');
            string username = usernamePasswordArray[0];
            string password = usernamePasswordArray[1];

            if (GSMSecurity.Login(username, password))
            {
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username), null);
            }
            else
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

I found the username using :

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

Comment: RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller inherits from `System.Web.Http.ApiController` you can access the `User` property:

```
[BasicAuthentication]
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    var name = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

In `BasicAuthentication`, do not forget to set the principal property correctly when signing in:

```
if (GSMSecurity.Login(username, password))
{
    var currentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username), null);
    actionContext.RequestContext.Principal = currentPrincipal;
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = currentPrincipal;
    HttpContext.Current.User = currentPrincipal;
}
```

Comment: I get a null value when trying this, I've added more information.

Comment: Updated the example

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider setting the principal on the HttpContext

```
if (GSMSecurity.Login(username, password)) {
    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username), null);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null) {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    }
}
```

And then accessing it via the `User` property on the `ApiController`

```
[BasicAuthentication]
public void Post([FromBody]string value) {
    // Get username from request for database lookup?
    var username = User.Identity.Name;
    //...
}
```

The framework will extract the user information from the context and associate it with the request context.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current user in the `RequestContext.Principal`